# How to get the value from td

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table td like below. if i use this.xml the below value coming.

```
<td xml="%3CGroup%20name%3D%22Menu%22%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%3E%3CTest%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20spacer%3D%221%22%20rights%3D%22Male%22%20action%3D%22onClick%22/%3E%20%3CRights%20width%3D%22100%22%20height%3D%22100%22%20spacer%3D%222%22%20rights%3D%22Female%22%20action%3D%22onClick%22/%3E%3C/Group%3E" 
onmouseover="rpiPopup.submover=true;top.window.rpiPopup.openSubMenu(event,this,this.xml,'SubMenu','Menu');" 
onmouseout="rpiPopup.submover=false;top.window.rpiPopup.hideSubMenu();">
```

How to get the xml value? It should work in all the browsers.

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace this.xml to

```
 this.getAttribute('xml')
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd give the `<td>` an id and then you can reference it.
So, with

```
<td id="myTd" xml="...">
```

you can reference it with the javascript

```
document.getElementById("myTd").getAttribute("xml");
```

Comment: or jQuery: `$("#myTD").attr("xml")`

Answer (score 0):

Give your `td` an id like so:

```
<td id="some_id" xml="YOUR_XML">...</td>
```

Then, you can easily get the xml attribute by doing this:

```
var myTd = document.getElementById("some_id");
var myXml = myTd.xml;
```

However, it seems to me like `xml` might be a non-standard attribute (someone correct me if I'm wrong). If you are using HTML 5 (or can use it), then it might be a good idea to use `data-xml` because you can legally make up your own attributes when they begin with `data-`. This would change your javascript to:

```
var myTd = document.getElementById("some_id");
var myXml = myTd["data-xml"];
```

If you use jQuery, it's slightly easier:

```
var myXml = $("#some_id").attr("data-xml");
```